# Stop SPD 2010 Workflow from Firing Multiple Times

Tags: 2010, workflow, email

I'm running SPD 2013 with a 2010 workflow.

I have a small email notification workflow that is triggered when the list workflow finishes.  The email workflow sends anywhere from 2-5 or more  duplicate emails after the list workflow completes processing. How do I stop this?

I’ve done a lot of research but fail to find an answer that works.  I have a STOP set at the end of the email WF but I believe it runs the list workflow again as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create additional column, choice column Mail Sent.
Default value should be No.
At the beginning of workflow add If clause. **If Mail Sent equals No** than do your job, send email or whatever you need to do.
At the end of the workflow add additional Update item function, where you should update column Mail Sent from No to Yes.
So next time workflow will not send emails due to If clause.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, but I forgot to mention that this email may need to be sent more than once and I don'w know how to start the workflow again once it was stopped by a condition.

Comment: In creating the above recommendation, I still get  5 or so emails.  Once I click Save on my form, the emails are received within 1-5 seconds.  I'm wondering if the server's response to the workflow is lagging behind.

Comment: You could possibly put a 'wait' clause in your workflow so that fields are saved etc as needed.